# Is unencrypted swap partition safe after shutdown in linux OS?

Tags: linux, partitioning, swap

I am trying to google this question, but so far I don't find any answer online.

I am running debian OS.

Unencrypted swap partition is NOT safe when the system is using it and running. Hackers may get sensitive data from the swap partition.

But what if the system is down? Will the swap partition leave any traces about the data?

For example, in an ext4/ntfs/fat32 partitions, even if the files are deleted, they still can be retreived/recovered by some softwares if those data are not rewriten/replaced by new data in the file system.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is unencrypted swap partition safe after shutdown?

## No!

Swap is not erased on shutdown - it would be very slow and rather harmful for SSDs. Even then, a clean shutdown isn't guaranteed - someone can simply pull the plug.